# C# Byte array split

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, split, byte

I have one question.

I want to split an array.

like this.

```
public static byte[][] Split(byte[] arr, byte keyword)
{
}

byte[] arr = {0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x00, 0x11};
var result = Split(arr, 0x00);
```

result:

```
{0x11, 0x22, 0x33}
{0x11, 0x22}
{0x11}
```

How can i programming this?

Comment: What do you want to happen if you have two (or more) consecutive zero values? An empty array or just skip it entirely?

Comment: Well, you'll need to scan through your original input... you might want to create a `List<byte[]>` in your method, to accumulate arrays as you go... what have you tried so far?

Comment: Should I show a reference to MoreLINQ, that already has implementation for [Split](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Split.cs?r=cbb78b95fd8609e5e5fb15798e14385357828ddc) for `IEnumerable<T>` ? The usage is `arr.Split(b => b == 0x00)` Produce exactly the same  output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick solution. I hope that help.

```
public static byte[][] Split(byte[] arr, byte keyword)
        {
            var result = new List<List<byte>>();

            var piece = new List<byte>();

            foreach (var b in arr)
            {
                if (b != keyword)
                {
                    piece.Add(b);
                }
                else
                {
                    result.Add(piece);
                    piece = new List<byte>();
                }
            }

            result.Add(piece);

            return ToArrayOfArray(result);
        }

public static T[][] ToArrayOfArray<T>(List<List<T>> list)
        {
            var res = new T[list.Count][];

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                res[i] = list[i].ToArray();
            }

            return res;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. But i must use only .net 2.0 i think Select method not supported in .net2.0...

Comment: You can refactor that portion of code with a method that using a list of lists return a array of arrays. That is simple. Then you have the full implementation.